# Why is this step necessary to prove $\lim_{x \to 2} x^2 = 4$?

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

I'm looking at third exercise in this [page](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Problems/CalcI/DefnOfLimit.aspx).

In the end of step 3, why is it necessary to assume that

\begin{equation}
5|x - 2| < \varepsilon
\end{equation}

Why would it be wrong if I had just stated that
\begin{align*}
|x + 2||x - 2| &< 5|x - 2|\\
&< 5\delta
\end{align*}

And if $5\delta = \varepsilon$, then the first implication is true when $|x - 2| < 1$. Thus, we can choose $\delta = \min\{1, \frac{\varepsilon}{5}\}$, because this would ensure $|x - 2| < 1$.

Comment: I think this is just one of the technicalities of this proof. You haven't assumed $ |x-2| < \delta $ at that stage, because you assumed it was lees than 1 for that logic. The magic happens when you choose delta at the end.

Comment: @theREALyumdub that is assumed at the start of the proof, it's in the definition of the limit.

Comment: Yes, but it is reassumed that $ |x - 2| < 1 $ at the start of step 3, so we're not clear on what  $ \delta $ is. If $ \delta < 1 $, we have a stronger claim and need to use $ \delta \leq \frac{\epsilon}{5} $.

Comment: I think this is the right logic but doesn't really amount to a most formal proof. You need to start with $ \delta $ in the proof, since you are assuming some $ \delta $ for any $ \epsilon $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the author does not assume that! The author only uses a phrase like "we want $\cdots$".

Let me show you a way to prove the proposition in one stroke. If $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then $|x^{2} - 4| = |x-2||x+2|$. The term $|x+2|$ is annoying here, so we may bound it away by bounding $|x-2|$. If in addition $|x-2| < 1$, then $|x| - 2 \leq |x-2| < 1$ by triangle inequality; so $|x| < 3$, and hence $|x+2| \leq |x| + 2 < 5$ by triangle inequality again. Then $|x-2||x+2| < 5|x-2|$. (note that we are still under the assumption that $|x-2| < 1$.) Given any $\varepsilon > 0$, we have $5|x-2| < \varepsilon$ if in addition $|x-2| < \varepsilon/5$ (corresponding to the author's "we want $\cdots$".). Now putting all these together suggests that taking $\delta := \min \{ 1, \varepsilon/5 \}$ suffices.

To be honest, your argument in its present form seems to me not convincing; it seems "fractional" you know. The most suspicious part is the paragraph beginning with "And". You may want to take some time to rethink how to phrase your thought. Perhaps you know it in your head, but it is just that you have not expressed it accurately.

Comment: @theREALyumdub, you kidding?

Comment: I'm not sure the triangle inequality says $ |x| - 2 \leq |x - 2| $, since $ |a| + |b| \geq |a + b| $. Those two were confusing me. But it is true, just not by the triangle inequality (it only works one way).

Comment: @theREALyumdub, it can be proved by triangle inequality. You can prove first that $||x| - 2| \leq |x-2|$.

Comment: Oh ok, by moving the $ -2 $ over... well alright. $ |x| = |x - 2 + 2| \leq |x - 2| + |2| $ ...

Comment: I understand the "we want" part now, but is the way I did it correct?

Comment: @cpassos, oh please revisit my answer :).

Comment: It does seem fishy, I just can't think of a way to prove it's wrong.

Comment: @cpassos, I don't think your argument in that form will be wrong something; it has just got a sense of incompleteness now :), like a sentence having not finished that kind of incompleteness.